# Should I apply both PRIMARY and UNIQUE indices on an id column of a MySQL InnoDB table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, primary-key, innodb

Having an InnoDB table with a simple single-column synthetic id primary key, should I only use PRIMARY index on the id column, or UNIQUE index too? Why?

Comment: My understanding of Primary key is "unique and not null". The implementation of a primary key is typically by a unique index (often implicitly). So is it unique and not null?

Comment: IMO: one or the other works, if you want to allow NULLS in PK, then use unique index.  If not, use PK.   Doing both serves no purpose UNLESS in the future you DROP the PK from a table; then the unique index will still cause uniqueness but now allow a "NULL"

Comment: @xQbert - In MySQL/InnoDB only the Primary Key can be the Clustered Index (afaik).  So, there is a subtle extra consideration too.

Answer (score 3):

Pk is enough, as it is also a unique key